# Migrating spring j_spring_security_check to login

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

Following the tutorial:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html

I have replaced in my login.jsp:

```
        <form name="login" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
```

into

```
        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login"/> 
        <form name="login" action="${loginUrl}" method="POST">
```

After I apply my login credentials I am getting a 404 on the http://localhost:8080/myApp/login

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the difference between `/login` and `/myApp/login`? What is the URL of your  login page? What URL did you enter to see the login page?

Comment: The url of the login page is:  http://localhost:8080/myApp/login.jsp

Comment: When I press 'apply' in the login page, the submit calls to the /myApp/login and then is when I am getting the 404

Comment: There should be a servlet provided by the sprin security listening in the myApp/login, but apparently it is not there.

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration. What URL do you have configured for your login page, `/login` or `/login.jsp`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the /login is automatically configured if your class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter contains @EnableWebSecurity